# Prevent Tablet Mode from maximizing window width

Tags: c#, wpf

In Windows 10, switching to Tablet Mode forces active windows to take the entire width and black out any underlying windows. We use small WPF windows as popup overlays for a dictionary tool. Most of the time they are not in focus, so the size stays right. However, if the user interacts with the popup, it will immediately expand. I can see several options for detecting Tablet Mode, but is there any way to prevent this from happening?

[image]

**Update.** Found this - perhaps it might help. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/81bc4436-998e-4f4c-beb2-7c5edc36047b/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-maximized?forum=vbgeneral

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your windows are not supposed to be maximized at all. Then why not just prevent it with:

```
    protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnStateChanged(e);
        if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
```

In your window class.